Lights (spotlight / directionalight) creating waves on my ground texture. How can I remove them?
I just encountered an issue with one of my three.js project. I've got a scene with some mapped objects. When I add some lights on the scene, some "waves" appeared on my scene.
enter image description here
My camera is moving around my scene and put those waves in motion and disturb the user.
When i remove the lights, those waves disappear.
enter image description here
Do you know where those waves come from ? And how can i get rid of them ?
I tried multiple sorts of lights but i'd like to use pointLights. The result is the same for each lights. I played with different lights settings but the waves persist.

The problem you are facing is named "Color banding".
Usually, in design with an image in Photoshop, you set a global layer of noise to undo the color bandings.
In code, it would consist in a postprocessing effect adding a noise on top to avoid color banding with gradient of color, example on a website with gradients.
The method to apply noise to avoid color banding is called dithering, and it is also implemented at the THREE.Material level with the property dithering. Setting dithering for your materials to true will (most likely) help.

Couple months ago I had the same “issue” with spotlight, in very close range in interactive plane gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0). I was wondering what anomaly was that. Now I know. Good one.
