ThreeJS point light gives weird texture look
I use ThreeJS, more specificaly React Three Fiber to create a 3D Canvas.
I added a glb model, point light and ambient light and the result was really bad.

Why does the texture look so choppy?
Is it because of the material or?
Thank you
I tried to edit intensity and color of the light. No change.
I added a normal cube, with a MeshStandardMaterial and it was okay.
This model was made in Blender, and shadows were baked a bit.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78542955/lights-spotlight-directionalight-creating-waves-on-my-ground-texture-how-ca

Tried adding dithering, but did not help

If you are using shadowmaps, try increasing your shadow bias.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow.bias
also it could potentially be an accuracy problem caused by too large or small of a model and your camera clip planes being too large giving it too little accuracy to discern front/back faces of the model.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far and also the near property.

It gave me a better result but I could never make it perfect. So far the best solution I had. Thank you
